# How can i detect when div is crosses over another div element on cdk drag and drop angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I use angular material cdk drag and drop on my project, first i create element dynamically
and then i drag it and drop on any position on my screen.

When i create 2 divs and drag div on div, is there is a way to know when the div dropped on other div ?

I want when  div is inside div to color the append div in other color.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, any findings on this?